# Error : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread : gemfire

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, windows-services, gemfire

Please before marking this duplicate read this : I have gone through all the answers provided for this error and nothing helped in my scenario.
I am doing a server migration where the same thing works well in 32 bit and 64 bit runs out of memory.

I have a windows service which internally points to .exe that spawns java process : I have made all the possible memory improvements in the config file of my .exe :Below:
I am not sure what different behavior is causing this out of memory for 64 bit server.(my java version is 1.8.xx)

```
#Java Additional Parameters
wrapper.java.additional.1=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
wrapper.java.additional.2=-XX:+UseParNewGC
wrapper.java.additional.3=-XX:ParallelGCThreads=8
wrapper.java.additional.4=-verbose:gc
# wrapper.java.additional.!!! should be sequence !!!=-Xloggc:D:\apps\Logs\gc.log
# wrapper.java.additional.!!! should be sequence !!!=-XX:+PrintGCDetails
# wrapper.java.additional.!!! should be sequence !!!=-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
wrapper.java.additional.5=-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=128m
wrapper.java.additional.6=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
wrapper.java.additional.7=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=34001
wrapper.java.additional.8=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
wrapper.java.additional.9=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
wrapper.java.additional.10=-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=55
wrapper.java.additional.11=-XX:NewSize=474m
wrapper.java.additional.12=-XX:MaxNewSize=474m
#wrapper.java.additional.13=-XX:PermSize=128m
#wrapper.java.additional.14=-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
wrapper.java.additional.15=-Xss128k
wrapper.java.additional.16=-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode
wrapper.java.additional.17=-XX:+UseCompressedOops
# Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.initmemory=1638
# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.maxmemory=1638
```

Still i am ending up to have :

**[severe 2016/10/24 06:27:46.192 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.SocketCreator.asyncClose(SocketCreator.java:688)**

Reading done for the concept here :

[Error reading](https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/unable-to-create-new-native-thread)

I am not much into Java things but tried all the things from my side , any help on this will be highly appreciated , i spend huge amount of time on this but not able to reach to any conclusion.

***********Update***************

So basically could figure out that this problem was coming due to excessive creation of thread from Gemfire which exceeds the threshold ~800 threads for Gemfire Java Process.

Here Jconsole tool helped to calculate the thread count , i could see around 200-300 threads from different pool getting created with no purpose apart from usual threads and they have discription as  :

```
Name: pool-9-thread-1
State: WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@163b285
Total blocked: 0  Total waited: 2

Stack trace: 
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'll add more details if i can find more on this !

*******Update 2 : ************
I could manage to see all the threads created by gemfire using Jconsole:
And this number keeps on increasing and after certain point of time i am seeing the OOM issue.Is there any way i can stop this unnecessary threads creation and memory conumption !

[image: Plenty of thread pools]

Comment: Same issue lister here : [link](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/411265?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: You'll have to diagnose it yourself. Use JVisualVM to connect to the process and see how many threads there are before crashing.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik : thanks for the response, I did that as well in parallel, will update my findings.I am just curious to know what wrapper.java.initmemory=1638 and wrapper.java.additional.15=-Xss128k impact on this.

Comment: `-Xss` could be a problem only if you set it to a pathologically large value. Using `initmemory` should be the same as using `additional.nn.-Xms`. and it's just about the starting point, it cannot cause an OOME.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik    thanks for above , yeah got it..!!! also the XMs value if i increse it which is basically heap size , is it going to help me in any form because as far i know thread creation totally depends on OS architecture.

Comment: Starting a new thread doesn't consume Java heap. But as I said, `-Xms` is not a limit so it's irrelevant. `-Xmx` is a limit (`java.maxmemory`). But heap is not your problem, so once again irrelevant.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik :  I have update and added some back ground happenings as well

Comment: There is each time a whole new threadpool being created. That may indicate an error in your code, where you keep creating new instances of Gemfire or whatever.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik : ok , well same dlls are deployed on two server and only one server showed all these pools getting created, will try to figure somethig more.Plus 32 bit servers do have same versions of Gemfire and there also i dont see these many pools getting created

Comment: There's no indication who's creating them because they have boilerplate default names.